# Look for a word within the folder name with VB scripting

Tags: vbscript, directory, filenames

How can i read a folder name with vb script and look for a particular word?

EG:

Folder name = 1234abc_Complete 
How can i get the text complete and store as a variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do as you require.

```
Option Explicit
' create a FileSystemObject
Dim oFso : Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' Set a reference to the folder which contains the folders you want to look through
Dim oFolder : Set oFolder = oFso.GetFolder("PathToFolderInHere")
Dim oSubFolder, myVar
' loop through each subfolder
For Each oSubFolder in oFolder.SubFolders
    ' If the oSubFolder contains the word complete then set myVar and exit the loop
    If InStr(1, oSubFolder.Name, "complete", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        myVar = oSubFolder.Name
        Exit For
    End If
Next

' do whatever with myVar (the folder name you wanted in the variable).
```